# Manage per-container IP addresses

Tags: linux, docker

On a Linux Docker host I want to run several containers, each providing a
separate service and each with its own ip address.  Do I need to provision the (VMware) VM of the host with extra NICs to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a network and then make containers a part of that network and assign an IP address to the containers.

Create a network:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 isolated_nw
```

Attach containers to the existing network:

```
docker run -itd --rm \
--network=isolated_nw \
--ip=172.25.3.3 \
--name=<assign_container_name> \
<image_name>
```